# Share animated GIF to Facebook using Javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

Now that Facebook supports the sharing of animated GIFs, I want to make a simple button that shares a selected GIF from a gallery, like this:

```
var obj = { 
    method: 'feed',
    source: 'http://img-9gag-fun.9cache.com/photo/aApVdqZ_460sa.gif',
    picture: 'http://img-9gag-fun.9cache.com/photo/aApVdqZ_460sa.gif',
    name: 'FB POST NAME GIF',
    caption: 'FB POST CAPTION GIF',
    description: 'FB POST MESSAGE GIF'
};
FB.ui(obj);
```

But it doesn't work.

If I post that URL directly, the wall works perfectly but through the action it (javascript) just makes a normal post as if it were a JPG.

Does anyone knows how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: I think that might be by design. http://www.forbes.com/sites/amitchowdhry/2015/06/01/facebook-starts-supporting-animated-gifs/

Comment: CBroe's right. You can only post images using the API right now.

Answer (score 1):

I've faced the same problem and I found a solution to post GIFs on Facebook

use the method `me/feed/` and put the gif url under the `link` object

example:

```
FB.api(
  'me/feed/',
  'POST',
  {
    message: 'This is a GIF',
    link: 'http://25.media.tumblr.com/08d54accc4beb56a50e752fd931c6b58/tumblr_mlsyqrzwWQ1s3g3ago1_400.gif'
  },
  function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  }
);
```

It worked for me I hope it works for you.

PS: I'm using the 2.5 API.