# FB.ui with picture param - Buggy?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I setup a facebook app and included this after :

```
<script>
            window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
                FB.init({
                    appId: 'HEREISMYAPPID',
                    xfbml: true,
                    version: 'v2.5'
                });
            };

            (function (d, s, id) {
                var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                if (d.getElementById(id)) {
                    return;
                }
                js = d.createElement(s);
                js.id = id;
                js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
                fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
            }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
        </script>
```

Now I made two methods. One is for sharing a text without picture and the other is for sharing a feed with a picture:

```
function sharefbimage(imgUrl, title, desc, spruchbildid) {
                FB.ui(
                        {
                            method: 'feed',
                            name: 'My App Name',
                            link: 'https://myurl.de/cdcd/'+spruchbildid,
                            caption: title,
                            description: desc,
                            picture: imgUrl
                        },
                function (response) {
                    if (response && response.post_id) {
                        alert('success');
                    } else {
                        alert('error');
                    }
                }
                );
            }

function sharefbtxt(spruch,spruchid) {
                FB.ui(
                        {
                            method: 'feed',
                            name: 'My App Name',
                            link: 'https://myurl.de/cdcd/'+spruchid,
                            caption: 'This is the best caption ever',
                            description: spruch
                        },
                function (response) {
                    if (response && response.post_id) {
                        alert('success');
                    } else {
                        alert('error');
                    }
                }
                );
            }
```

If I share a text through calling "sharefbtext" everything works as expected. If I press the cancel button the popup closes and I'm getting the response alert.

If I call "sharefbimage" with a "picture" parameter the dialog opens as expected and the image is loaded as expected. You can post the feed and it appears on the wall. The only thing which is not working is that if one is pressing the cancel button it doesn't close the dialog so the response alert never shows. After pressing cancel or post, the feed only redirects to "https://www.facebook.com/v2.5/dialog/feed" but the dialog won't close...

So am I missing something or is this a bug?

Answer (score 0):

I've used the Facebook API 2.5 Javascript SDK and here's what I did to post a photo on users profile (in this case my profile):

```
FB.api(
  'me/photos/',
  'POST',
  {
    message: 'This is a photo',
    url: 'image link'
  },
  function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  }
);
```

This will create a new album with the name of your app, btw if you want to post a GIF see my answer here :
[Share animated GIF to Facebook using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34588949/4341572)

Comment: @JanineKroser ok try changing the method in your code from `feed` to `photos`

Comment: Then I believe FB.ui is not the right function, try the FB.api as I mentioned above. All of Facebook examples are using it.